# Why does the ajax GET request only work for the first item in the foreach loop?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to populate a 'transaction model' form with previously entered data if the user wants to 'edit' the transaction. The transaction is being passed into the View as a `IEnumerable<Transaction>`. I'm displaying each transaction in a table with each row containing a transaction and actions that can be performed on it. Once the user clicks edit I've set up a modal to popup with the form inside. In order to populate the form I've created a jquery GET request each time the user clicks on edit this requests retrieves the transaction from the database and returns the properties that I want as json data. The problem is that this request works for the first transaction in the IEnumerable.

Here is my View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="TransactionTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Reconciled</th>
                    <th>Updated By</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var t in Model.Transactions)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@t.Created</td>
                        <td>
                            @t.Description
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @t.Category.Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @t.Amount
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if(t.Reconciled == 0)
                            {
                                <span class="fa fa-check-square-o"></span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @t.Reconciled
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @t.UpdatedBy.DisplayName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x editform" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-@t.Id" id="editform" data-transaction-id="@t.Id"></a>

                            <!--Edit Modal Begin-->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="edit-@t.Id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Transaction &nbsp; <span class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></span></h4>
                                        </div>

                                                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                                                {
                                                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccountId)
                                                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <!--Description-->
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Transaction.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Transaction.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Transaction.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                        </div>
                                                        <!--Amount. +/- -->
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Transaction.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Transaction.Amount, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Transaction.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Transaction.IsIncome, true, new { @checked = true, }) Deposit
                                                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Transaction.IsIncome, false) Purchase
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Transaction.Reconciled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Transaction.Reconciled, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Transaction.Reconciled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <div class="ui-widget">
                                                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Transaction.Category, "Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                                                                @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, "-- select a category --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "categories" })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Transaction.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Transaction.Created, "Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Transaction.Created, new { @class = "form-control", id = "datepicker1" })
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-success">Reset</button>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-facebook" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                                                    </div>

                                                }


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <a href="#" class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "HouseAccount", new {householdid = Model.Account.HouseHoldId })" >Back to List &nbsp;<<</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript below the view:

```
@section page{
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#editform').click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Transaction/EditTransactionInfo/',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',                
                data: { transId: $("#editform").data('transaction-id') },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.Description);
                }
            })
        })
        $('#TransactionTable').DataTable();
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker();
    </script>
}
```

And my request controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult EditTransactionInfo(int transId)
{
    var trans = db.Transactions.Find(transId);
    return Json(new { Description = trans.Description,
                      Amount = trans.Amount,

    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're outputting your `<a id=#editform>` in a loop, which means you're producing MULTIPLE duplicate IDs. DOM ids **MUST** be unique through the entire document.

Since you have duplicates, `$('#editform')` will return only the FIRST matching element it finds - it will not return any others, since it's not supposed to.

Either change to using a class instead of an id to tag the `<a>` elements, or use the `event` you capture inside the on-click and extract the click target from that instead.

Comment: This + Consider using a partial view for your edit popup. And put your main popup div in the layout so you can use it on any page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I've had this issue before but I didn't really understand how I solved it now I know why! Thanks happy memorial day

Comment: Thats a pretty good idea I will do that to make the view not as messy. Our instructor has mention before that too many partial views means the view engine has to work more each time you load a page you load it several times. Is this really an issue? I personally like it cause it keeps things modular

Answer (score 1):

You create multiple ID's for DOM. Instead `id` use `class` attribute inside `foreach` and `$(".className")` in your jQuery selectors.